# pnp4nagios only displays first graph returned by check_int.pl

Tags: nagios

I am having difficulty getting more than one graph worth of perfdata to display using pnp4nagios with naemon.
It appears the format is not what Nagios is expecting to pass to pnp4nagios.
I think I have the most recent version of check_int.pl:
Program : check_netint.pl or check_snmp_netint.pl
Version : 2.4 alpha 9
Date    : Nov 30, 2012

The perfdata format looks ok.  In others that work with multiple graphs there seem to be an equivalent number of entries on the left side of the "|" as the right side.  I've also tried entering in
-w and -c values so the ;;; below are filled with those.  This does not seem to make a difference.

I'd like to get 4 graphs from the below return data, in/out for each of the two interfaces.
Any ideas?

```
 %   /usr/lib64/naemon/plugins//check_int.pl -H 10.61.146.227 -C sparkred -2 -n bond0  -w -z -f -e -S -k -Y -B


 bond0:UP (1717.9Kbps/3854.1Kbps), bond0.1422:UP (19.0Kbps/326.0Kbps) (2 UP): OK |  'bond0_in_bps'=1717881;;; 'bond0_out_bps'=3854092;;;  'bond0.1422_in_bps'=19023;;; 'bond0.1422_out_bps'=325999;;;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the *pnp4nagios* **template** written specifically for this particular Nagios plugin.

Try downloading:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/willixix/WL-NagiosPlugins/master/graphing_templates/pnp4nagios/check_snmp_network_interface_linux.php

and placing it in your pnp4nagios *templates* folder.
On my system, this path ends up being:

```
/usr/local/pnp4nagios/share/templates/check_snmp_network_interface_linux.php
```

Then restart the nagios service.

Here's more information about pnp4nagios templates:
http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/tpl

This is the site of the Nagios plugin's author:
http://william.leibzon.org/nagios/